# Intellej Idea deleted my project, what is happened?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

[image]

I have the same problem like described in this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206877445-Please-help-IntelliJ-11-just-deleted-all-my-files-?page=1#comments

Whole project was disappeared (even .git file), what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you see it on the file system? IntelliJ IDEA does not have any actions to remove the whole project except manual way

Comment: Try Local history?